# Showing Flatpickr dates in local timezone, but sending server UTC?

Tags: datetime, format, flatpickr, luxon

Here's how I'm setting up Flatpickr:

```
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';
import { DateTime } from "luxon";

flatpickr(`#${this.el.id}`, {
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: 'M d Y h:i K',
    formatDate: (date, format, locale) => {
        // ?
    }
});
```

This sends the datetimes back to my backend as UTC which is fine, but I want to show the datetimes  in my users local timezone.

How can I accomplish this with Flatpickr and luxon?

Comment: Where you able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue.